# A make rule for verbosity

Tags: makefile

Typically we have this in a Makefile

```
%.o:%.c
    $(cc) $(flags) -o $@ -c $<
```

When the amount of flags is huge, I feel better to write this instead

```
%.o:%.c
    $(info $(cc):   $<  --> $@)
    @$(cc) $(flags) -o $@ -c $<
```

However it can be useful to sometime see everything. So I defined a variable for that:

```
at=@

%.o:%.c
    $(info $(cc):   $<  --> $@)
    $(at)$(cc) $(flags) -o $@ -c $<
```

My question is how to properly, easily set or unset `$(at)` from the command line. I see two solutions:

```
$ make verbose all
$ make verbose=1 all
```

With the first solution I would do this

```
ifeq (,$(filter verbose,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
at=@
dummy:=$(filter-out verbose,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
endif
```

With the second I might do this

```
ifeq (,$(filter 1,$(verbose)))
at=@
endif
```

Is both solutions acceptable or can I do better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally set up my makefiles like this:

- Recipe lines that I know I will never want to see the commands reported begin with `@` (typically this is just any `echo` statements or other similar meta-statements).
- All other recipe lines do NOT prefix with `@`.
- I add the `.SILENT:` psuedo-target to make the output silent by default.
- I prefix (or suffix) the `.SILENT:` psuedo-target with a variable reference, like `$V`.

So, something like this:

```
%.o: %.c
        @echo '$(cc):   $<  --> $@'
        $(cc) $(flags) -o $@ -c $<

$V.SILENT:
```

Now by default `V` is not set, so the last line expands to the [`.SILENT` special target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002eSILENT) and no recipe commands are shown.  If I run `make V=1` (or any other value) then the target expands to `1.SILENT:` which is nothing special to make and so is essentially ignored, and all my commands that are NOT prefixed with `@` are printed.